# Why does my antivirus keep alerting me that someone attempted to remote access my computer?

Tags: antivirus, windows-10, remote-desktop

I have purchased AVG's premium service to use on a Windows 10 operating system, but it almost seems like since I have gotten it, (had it for about a month now) it keeps alerting me that it has blocked someone from remote accessing my computer.

These alerts seem almost random in time but looking at the logs shows multiple blocked attempts over several minutes before it seemingly gives up.

It may be worth noting that I go to and stay at a JobCorps center, which has government provided wifi. Whether this means anything or not I don't know since I haven't had the chance to go somewhere else to try their wifi because of Covid.

I have also scanned my com multiple times over since the occurrence with no red flags. Is this just a false alarm? Is there something I should do to better protect myself?

Comment: What ports? From the same ip addresses or different ones?

Comment: You may have a service exposed that you don't need.  In the event viewer, look in the security logs (under the windows logs).  Are you seeing the login attempts there?  If so, look at the details and you should see the remote IP address that these attempts are originating from, and the protocol of the login attempts. If these login attempts are on a service that you are not using, then you may want to shutdown this service.  If they are on a service that you are using, but from IP addresses that you do not expect, then you may want to create tighter rules in Windows Firewall.

Comment: More detailed information about the alerts is necessary.